# Save and restore fragment views state on configuration chages

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

EDIT

I've been searching and reading a lot about this topic and I just can't find the solution for my problem. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or designing wrong or what.

I have one fragment in my activity, this fragment has three different layouts that appears or disappear (this depends of what the user did or is doing). Also a viewgroup is create dynamically adding new TextViews. I want to keep, as they are, all the views of my fragment when the orientation of the screen change, leaving the layouts that are invisible like that, keeping all the TextViews like they are, etc.

I know how works the lifecycle of the fragment and activity when the screen orientation changes, but I don't know how to manage that. How and from where recover the fragment that is still in memory, how to recover the view like it was and return it in onCreateView. I'm quit confuse about this.

Here is the xml the fragment

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:weightSum="1">

<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:background="#fc033967">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="@string/scan_new_code_location"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:id="@+id/location_textView" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/new_location_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/new_location_image"
                    android:layout_width="18dp"
                    android:layout_height="18dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_new"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/boton_nuevaLoc"
                    android:text="@string/newLocation"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    />

        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/cancel_ingress_layout"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/location_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="#fc033967">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/location_image"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_mylocation"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/added_location_textView"
            android:text="@string/newLocation"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/close_location_container"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/close_location_image"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>



<EditText
        android:id="@+id/scan_reader_EditText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="500dp"
        android:inputType="text"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is part of the code

```
public class LocationFragment extends Fragment {


    private static final String TAG = "LocationFragment";
    private static final String CSV = ".csv";
    private final int scapeChar = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER;
    private final int MODE_FIRST = 0;
    private final int SHARED_INTENT = 1;

    //Graphics elements
    @Bind(R.id.top_layout) RelativeLayout topLayout;
    @Bind(R.id.new_location_layout) LinearLayout addLocationLayout;
    @Bind(R.id.new_location_image) ImageButton newLocationImage;
    @Bind(R.id.boton_nuevaLoc) Button newLocationButton;
    @Bind(R.id.cancel_ingress_layout) RelativeLayout cancelScanLayout;
    @Bind(R.id.location_textView) TextView locationTextView;
    @Bind(R.id.scan_reader_EditText) EditText scanReaderEditText;
    @Bind(R.id.container) ViewGroup containerLayout;
    @Bind(R.id.location_container) RelativeLayout closeLayout;
    @Bind(R.id.added_location_textView) TextView addedLocation;
    @Bind(R.id.close_location_image) ImageButton closeImageButton;
    static ViewGroup panelIngresarItem;


    private boolean scanLocationMode;
    private float translation;
    private DatabaseManager dbm = DatabaseManager.getInstance();
    private String locationCode;
    private Location location;
    private List<Item> items;
    private View.OnClickListener addItemListener;
    private String folderPath;



    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public LocationFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static LocationFragment newInstance() {
        LocationFragment fragment = new LocationFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this,rootView);
        return rootView;
    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        locationTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        translation = topLayout.getMeasuredWidth() - addLocationLayout.getMeasuredWidth() +
                newLocationButton.getMeasuredWidth();
        cancelScanLayout.setOnClickListener(new CloseButtonListener());
        cancelScanLayout.setClickable(false);

        // Add item listener, for only create one listener
        addItemListener = new AddItemListener();

        closeImageButton.setOnClickListener(new CloseLocationListener());

        panelIngresarItem = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(this.getActivity()).inflate(
                R.layout.new_item_panel,containerLayout,false);
        panelIngresarItem.setOnClickListener(addItemListener);

        scanLocationMode = true;
        closeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        super.onViewCreated(view,savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        containerLayout.removeAllViews();
        populateItemList();
    }


    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }


    private void addLocationAnimation(){
        RotateAnimation ranim = (RotateAnimation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.rotate_image);
        ranim.setDuration(400);
        ranim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        ranim.setFillAfter(true);
        ranim.setFillEnabled(true);

        translation = topLayout.getMeasuredWidth() - addLocationLayout.getMeasuredWidth() +
                newLocationButton.getMeasuredWidth();

        newLocationButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        TranslateAnimation anim =
                new TranslateAnimation(0,translation,0,0);
        anim.setDuration(400);
        anim.setFillAfter(true);
        anim.setFillEnabled(true);
        newLocationImage.startAnimation(ranim);
        addLocationLayout.startAnimation(anim);

        cancelScanLayout.setClickable(true);

        locationTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        enableScanner();

    }

    private void populateItemList(){
        if (location != null) {
            containerLayout.removeAllViews();
            containerLayout.addView(panelIngresarItem);
            items = dbm.getItemListByLocation(location);
            for (Item e : items) {
                String code = e.getInventoryCode();
                addItem(code);
            }
        }
    }

    private void callItemEditForm(String code) {
        Intent itemFormActivity = new Intent(getActivity(),ItemFormActivity.class);
        itemFormActivity.putExtra("Item", code);
        itemFormActivity.putExtra("Location",locationCode);
        startActivity(itemFormActivity);
    }

    private void scanLocation(String code){
        folderPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+
                File.separator+getResources().getString(R.string.folder)+File.separator
                + locationCode;
        if (dbm.existLocation(code)){
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setTitle(R.string.dialog_tittle)
                    .setMessage(R.string.dialog_message)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.positive_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            removeHoleDB();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.negative_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        }
                    })
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .show();
        }
        locationCode = code;
        containerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        location = dbm.getLocation(locationCode);
        scanLocationMode = false;
        addedLocation.setText(locationCode);
        topLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        closeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        containerLayout.addView(panelIngresarItem);
        populateItemList();
    }

    private void addItem (String code) {
        ((TextView)panelIngresarItem.findViewById(R.id.new_item_textView)).setText(code);
        ((ImageView)panelIngresarItem.findViewById(R.id.new_item_image)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        panelIngresarItem.setOnClickListener(null);
        //TODO add listener
        panelIngresarItem = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(this.getActivity()).inflate(
                R.layout.new_item_panel,containerLayout,false);
        panelIngresarItem.setOnClickListener(addItemListener);
        containerLayout.addView(panelIngresarItem,0);
    }


    @OnClick(R.id.boton_nuevaLoc) void addNewLocation(){
        addLocationAnimation();
    }

    class CloseButtonListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            locationTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            RotateAnimation ranim = (RotateAnimation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.rotate_image_back);
            ranim.setDuration(400);
            ranim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            ranim.setFillAfter(true);
            ranim.setFillEnabled(true);
            newLocationButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            TranslateAnimation anim =
                    new TranslateAnimation(translation,0,0,0);
            anim.setDuration(400);
            anim.setFillAfter(true);
            anim.setFillEnabled(true);
            newLocationImage.startAnimation(ranim);
            addLocationLayout.startAnimation(anim);
            disableScanner();
            cancelScanLayout.setClickable(false);
        }
    }

    private class BarcodeEdittextListener implements TextView.OnEditorActionListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if ( (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) ||
                    (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && event.getKeyCode() == scapeChar ){
                String code = v.getText().toString();
                    if(!code.equals("")) {
                        if (scanLocationMode)
                            scanLocation(code);
                        else {
                            addItem(code);
                            callItemEditForm(code);
                        }
                        v.setText("");
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            return false;
        }
    }

    class AddItemListener implements View.OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            callItemEditForm("N/A");
        }
    }


    class CloseLocationListener implements View.OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            deleteAndSend();
            /*
            new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setTitle(R.string.dialog_tittle)
                    .setMessage(R.string.dialog_message)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.positive_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            deleteAndSend();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.negative_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        }
                    })
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .show();
                    */
        }
    }

}
```

and the activity code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private FragmentManager fm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container_fragment, new LocationFragment())
                .commit();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_other);
    }

}
```

***************EDIT***********************

OK. I solved it thanks to Endzeit.

I need to do this:
In my fragment I create a View variable to reference the view to the fragment and retain the instance.
Then if there was a saved instance I return in onCreateView the reference to the view I've saved. Like this:
    public class LocationFragment extends Fragment {

```
    private static final String TAG = "LocationFragment";

    //Graphics elements
    @Bind(R.id.top_layout) RelativeLayout topLayout;
                .
                .
                .
    static ViewGroup panelIngresarItem;
    **View rootView**;


    public LocationFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static LocationFragment newInstance() {
        LocationFragment fragment = new LocationFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        **setRetainInstance(true)**;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        **if (savedInstanceState == null)** {
            **rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location, container, false);**
            ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
        }

        **return rootView;**
    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState){

        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            locationTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            translation = topLayout.getMeasuredWidth() - addLocationLayout.getMeasuredWidth() +
                    newLocationButton.getMeasuredWidth();
            cancelScanLayout.setOnClickListener(new CloseButtonListener());
            cancelScanLayout.setClickable(false);

            // Add item listener, for only create one listener
            addItemListener = new AddItemListener();

            closeImageButton.setOnClickListener(new CloseLocationListener());

            panelIngresarItem = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(this.getActivity()).inflate(
                    R.layout.new_item_panel, containerLayout, false);
            panelIngresarItem.setOnClickListener(addItemListener);

            scanLocationMode = true;
            closeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        }
    }
                .
                .
                .

}
```

And then in the activity put the fragment in the FragmentManager and take it again if there is a saved instance

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private FragmentManager fm;
    public static final String FRAG_LOCATION = "frag_loc";
    private LocationFragment fragmentLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            fragmentLocation = new LocationFragment();
        } else {
            fragmentLocation = (LocationFragment) fm
                    .getFragment(savedInstanceState,FRAG_LOCATION);
        }

        fm.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container_fragment, fragmentLocation)
                .commit();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_other);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        if(fragmentLocation != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState,FRAG_LOCATION, fragmentLocation);
        }

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
                            .
                            .
                            .

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm asuming you want to save your fragment's and activity's state on rotation for example.

You have to save the fragment on your activities `onSaveInstanceState()` method.

To achieve that change your code to something like:

```
    public static final String TAG_FRAG_LOCATION = "key_frag_loc";  
    private LocationFragment fragmentLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        fragmentLocation = (LocationFragment) fragmentManager
                .findFragmentByTag(savedInstanceState.getString(TAG_FRAG_LOCATION));
    } else {
        fragmentLocation = new LocationFragment(); 
    }

    fm.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container_fragment, fragmentLocation)
                .commit();

     ...
    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        if(fragmentLocation != null) {
            outState.putString(TAG_FRAG_EXAMS, fragmentLocation.getTag());
        }

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```